# How to hide input file type but still display the file uploaded?

Tags: html, css

I have a code that has an input file type that is hidden but called on from the paperclip icon, however it doesnt show the user that a file has been chosen for upload.[image: This is what I have]

If i remove display none from the input field you will see "Choose a file" along with the file I chose. is there a way just to show the file once it has been uploaded, for example:
[image]

Here is the code I have so far:

```
<div class="chat-right">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" style="display:none;" id="hidden_upload_file_chatting">

    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assest/icon-img/paperclip.png" class="ic_img" onclick="$('input#hidden_upload_file_chatting').click();">

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat" name="reply" value="reply" >Reply</button>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 10px !important;">Close</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you also share CSS? Thanks

Comment: You can not do that by simply hiding the input field, you need a custom implementation for something like this. https://tympanus.net/Tutorials/CustomFileInputs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just write a basic code snippet for file open on a icon click. Try this I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.chat-right {
  display: flex;
}

.fileUploadWrap {
  background-image: url('https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/budicon-document-2/16/69-document_-_attachment_clip_paperclip-512.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
}

#hidden_upload_file_chatting {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="chat-right">
  <div class="fileUploadWrap">
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" id="hidden_upload_file_chatting">
  </div>
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat" name="reply" value="reply" >Reply</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 10px !important;">Close</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var fileBtn = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
var sName = document.getElementById('_showName');

fileBtn.addEventListener('change', function(_th){
 if(this.files.length)
    sName.innerText = this.files[0].name;
 else
     sName.innerText = '';
});
```

```html
<div class="chat-right">
<label>  
    <img src="<?php echo base_url();?>/assest/icon-img/paperclip.png" class="ic_img" >
    <span id="_showName"></span>
    <input type="file" name="file" class="form-control" style="display:none;" id="fileUpload">
</label>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-flat" name="reply" value="reply" >Reply</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-flat" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-left: 10px !important;">Close</button>
</div>
```